# Value counts by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new to pandas and I want to be able to get number of instances for each person and feed it into a another Dataframe as a column. I've removed the NaN values from the dataframe before I made the group by the user column

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
DF["NumInstances"] = userGrp["user"].value_counts()
```

I've look over the internet, but can't seem to find a solution, please help.

Edit: Sample Data and Expected Outcome

```
[{"user" : "4",
"Instance": "21"},
 {"user" : "4",
"Instance": "6"},
{"user" : "5",
"Instance" : "546453"}]
```

Expected outcome:

DataFrame =

```
[{"user":"4",
 "NumInstances" : "2"},
 {"user":"5",
 "NumInstances" : "1"}]
```

So basically counts how many times the instance occurs for each user across data entries.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I need it in order defined by the group so that I can match up the user to the number of instances

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe input with expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Just added those edits in. Thanks for the advice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @AgentArachnid Have put an answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample input, you can do this:

```
In [2535]: df = pd.DataFrame([{"user" : "4", 
      ...: "Instance": "21"}, 
      ...:  {"user" : "4", 
      ...: "Instance": "6"}, 
      ...: {"user" : "5", 
      ...: "Instance" : "546453"}])  

In [2539]: df.groupby('user', as_index=False).count()
Out[2539]: 
  user  Instance
0    4         2
1    5         1
```

Comment: Yeah, I made a slight alteration and it seemed to have worked:
InstancePerUser.groupby('user', as_index=False)['Instance'].count()

Answer (score 0):

if DF is the name of your dataset and "user" the name of the column you want to groupby for, then try:

count = DF.groupby("user").count()

print(count)

Comment: I got this error: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution that will create a new dataframe which contains both column named "user" and "NumInstances" :

```py
df_counts = df.groupby(['user']).size().reset_index(name='NumInstances')
```

Hope it helps.